# How to fix 404 Not Found when sending GET/POST requests to express server via Angular App and NodeJS

Tags: node.js, angular, rest, http

I am trying to create an Angular app that sends GET & POST requests to an express server using NodeJS.

When I serve the app, GET & POST requests are meant to be sent to my local server, but I'm getting an error in the console, this error is logged below.

Also, when I go to localhost:3000, the server is running.

Here is my component class:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import { RootService } from "./root.service";

@Component({
  selector: "app-root",
  templateUrl: "./root.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./root.component.css"]
})
export class RootComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private rootService: RootService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.rootService.getAPIData().subscribe(
      response => {
        console.log("response from GET API is ", response);
      },
      error => {
        console.log("error is ", error);
      }
    );

    this.rootService.postAPIData().subscribe(
      response => {
        console.log("response from POST API is ", response);
      },
      error => {
        console.log("error during post is ", error);
      }
    );
  }
}
```

And here is root.service.ts:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class RootService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getAPIData(){
    return this.http.get('/api/getData')
  }

  postAPIData(){
return this.http.post('/api/postData', {'firstName' : 'Code', 'lastName' : 'Handbook'})
  }
}
```

Here is my server code:

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
res.send('Welcome to Node API')
})

app.get('/getData', (req, res) => {
res.json({'message': 'Hello World'})
})

app.post('/postData', bodyParser.json(), (req, res) => {
res.json(req.body)
})

app.listen(3000, () => console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!'))
```

I also have this proxy.conf.json file:

```
{
  "/api/*": {
    "target": "http://localhost:3000",
    "pathRewrite": {"^/api" : ""}
  }
}
```

When I serve my app, I get the following output to the console:

> error is
>   Object { headers: {…}, status: 404, statusText: "Not Found", url: "http://localhost:4200/api/getData", ok: false, name: "HttpErrorResponse", message: "Http failure response for http://localhost:4200/api/getData: 404 Not Found", error: "\n\n\n\nError\n\n\n
>
> ```
> Cannot GET /api/getData
> ```
>
> \n\n\n" }
>   root.component.ts:18:8
>   error during post is
>   Object { headers: {…}, status: 404, statusText: "Not Found", url: "http://localhost:4200/api/postData", ok: false, name: "HttpErrorResponse", message: "Http failure response for http://localhost:4200/api/postData: 404 Not Found", error: "\n\n\n\nError\n\n\n
>
> ```
> Cannot POST /api/postData
> ```
>
> \n\n\n" }

Can someone please help me with this error?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to pass in the path to `proxy.conf` when you start the Angular app.

Ref: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/master/docs/documentation/stories/proxy.md

Answer (score 0):

Your config should look like:

```
{
  "/api": {
    "target": "http://localhost:3000",
    "pathRewrite": {
      "^/api": ""
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi, I've updated my proxy.cons.json but I'm still getting the same error unfortunately

Comment: Did you include this in your webpack config?

Comment: Did you use this command to start?:
```ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.json```

Comment: I have `"start": "ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.json",` in my package.json

Comment: What's in devTools? If you add a route with ```/api``` to your node server - is there catch your request? What port does your HTTP client use to send requests?

Comment: I'm using localhost:4200 for the angular app, & the server is hosted on localhost:3000

Comment: Yep. I got that its different servers. But what is host using for sending requests by HttpClient? Maybe the reason here?

Answer (score 0):

**1. First make a file **"proxy.config.json"** on root directory and add these lines inside:**

```
{
  "/api/*": {
    "target": "http://localhost:3000",
    "secure": false,
    "logLevel": "debug"
  }
}
```

**2. On "**angular.json"** under script put:**

```
     "start": "ng serve --proxy-config proxy.config.json",
```

**3. On terminal write "npm start"**

```
  note: Don't write "ng serve" , it won't run proxy configuration file.
```